# How to take a screenshot on failure using hound/elixir

Tags: elixir, hound

I am trying to take a screenshot using take_screenshot() (Hound). I just need to capture the screenshot on failure.

I have tried try/rescue however rescue block always executed even though assertion fails.

```
try do
   // some page elements action
   assert visible_page_text(), "Hello World"
rescue
  _ -> take_screenshot()
end
```

I also tried,

```
try do
   // some page elements action
   assert visible_page_text(), "Hello World"
catch
  _ -> take_screenshot()
end
```

I want,
if assertion fails, only then it should take screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

With a small modification your code works:

```
try do
   // some page elements action
   assert visible_page_text() =~ "Hello World"
catch
  error ->
    take_screenshot()
    raise error
end
```

Or turn it into a macro:

```
  # assert screenshot on failure
  defmacro assert_sof(assertion) do
    quote do
      try do
        assert unquote(assertion)
      rescue
        error ->
          take_screenshot()
          raise error
      end
    end
  end
```

And call it like this:

```
assert_sof visible_page_text() =~ "Hello World"
```

**Update**: As you mentioned, this will only take screenshots when doing an assertion. That can be fixed though.

Here is a macro that will wrap the contents of a whole test in a try/rescue block and save a screenshot on any error. As a bonus, it prefixes the screenshot with the name of the test. <strike>The big drawback is that you lose the stracktrace, so it's harder to pinpoint the failing line of test code.</strike> (solved with `catch` instead of `rescue`) Put the macro in `support/conn_case.ex` or somewhere else if you prefer:

```
def MyAppWeb.ConnCase
  # ...

  # Test and take screenshot on failure. Only works for hound tests.
  defmacro test_sof(message, var \\ quote do _ end, contents) do
    prefix = String.replace(message, ~r/\W+/, "-")
    filename = Hound.Utils.temp_file_path(prefix, "png")

    quote do
      test unquote(message), unquote(var) do
        try do
          unquote(contents)
        catch
          error ->
            take_screenshot(unquote(filename))
            raise error
        end
      end
    end
  end

  using do
    quote do
      # Import conveniences for testing with connections
      use Phoenix.ConnTest
      import MyAppWeb.ConnCase, only: [test_sof: 2, test_sof: 3] # <- Add this line
      # ...
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

And call it like a normal test:

```
test_sof "form with valid data" do
  navigate_to "/form"
  click({:id, "test"})
  assert visible_page_text() =~ "test successful"
end
```

Now it should work for all kinds of errors.

Comment: Great that worked as intended. However if Test fails (other steps than assert, su as element not found), it wont capture snapshot.

Comment: Ok, that's a pity. Although it works as intended if I test something like `assert_sof element_displayed?({:class, "foobar"})` when it's not there. It takes a screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added a new macro that works for a whole test, not only for assertions.